# How can I create input field for saveMany() in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have written name[] for insert multiple name using cakephp saveMany() method.

```
<?= $this->Form->control('name[]',['label'=>'Name']);?>
```

Problem is I'm getting the array like

```
[
  'name' => [
    (int) 0 => 'A',
    (int) 1 => 'B',
  ],
]
```

Getting error message `Cake\ORM\Table::saveMany(): Argument #1 ($entities) must be of type iterable`

How can I create name input field for multiple insert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form helper's dot syntax with indices, that is `0.name`, `1.name`, `2.name`, etc., this will result in data formatted like

```php
[
    0 => [
        'name' => 'A',
    ],
    1 => [
        'name' => 'B',
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'C',
    ],
    // ...
]
```

And then use `Table::newEntities()` / `Table::patchEntities()` to create/patch multiple entities at once.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Field Naming Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting Request Data into Entities > Converting Multiple Records](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Multiple Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities)**